# Как остановить выполнение функции Python по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python

Есть функция, которая выполняется какое то произвольное кол-во времени. Мне нужно сделать хоткей, что бы при его использовании, выполнение функции прекращалось.

Я пробовал создать переменную isFuncActive и по нажатию на хоткей менять ее значение на False, а в самой функции в разных частях вставил проверку и в случае False, делал return. Но пока функция активна хоткей не работает.

Выглядит примерно следующим образом. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно, что бы по нажатию на хоткей функция прерывалась

```
isFuncActive = True

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 1', func)
keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 1', stop)

def stop():
  isFuncActive = False

def func():
  // some code
  if isFuncActive == False: return
  // some code
  if isFuncActive == False: return
  // some code
  if isFuncActive == False: return
  // some code
  if isFuncActive == False: return
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы работаете в одном потоке, и при нажатии на любую кнопку до истечения  выполнения программы ничего не произойдёт, но да вы смотрите в правильном направлении использование переменных-флагов, является одним из решений. Поищите threading в python.

Comment: А вот комментарии в питоне не так ставятся

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, думаю это то что нужно мне. За комментарии знаю, просто одновременно сейчас пишу и на js и на питоне и моментами синтаксис могу путать от запары :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема здесь в том, что когда вы нажимаете горячую клавишу для остановки функции `func()`, она все еще может выполняться в фоновом режиме. Именно поэтому ваши проверки, которые вставлены в разных частях функции и отвечают за ее прерывание, не срабатывают.

Решение можно состоит в том, чтобы использовать потоки (threads) для выполнения функции `func()`. Это позволит нам запустить функцию в отдельном потоке, который можно будет остановить, когда пользователь нажмет горячую клавишу.

Для этого вам нужно сделать следующее:

1. Импортируйте модуль threading:

```py
import threading
```

2. Создайте объект-поток из функции `func()`:

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
```

3. Запустите поток:

```py
thread.start()
```

4. В функции `stop()` измените переменную `isFuncActive` и остановите поток:

```py
def stop():
  global isFuncActive # добавляем global, чтобы изменения были глобальными
  isFuncActive = False
  thread.join() # останавливаем поток
```

5. В функции `func()` добавьте проверку на `isFuncActive` внутри цикла выполнения функции:

```py
def func():
  # some code
  while isFuncActive:
    # some code
  # some final code
```

Теперь при нажатии на горячую клавишу `stop()` изменит значение `isFuncActive` на `False`, что позволит выполнению функции `func()` завершиться.

Comment: В каком ещё фоновом режиме? До того, как её в поток вынесли?

Comment: В питоне достаточно глобальной переменной для таких проверок? Никаких volatile или специальных классов для межпоточного взаимодействия не надо?